# Execution failed for task ':common:compileJava'. > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, lombok

Getting the error whenever adding the lombok 1.16.20 or the gradle task is running perfectly, here is the build script, however it is running on the intelliJ but not able to make use the gradle clean build.

Erro stack is :
Execution failed for task ':common:compileJava'. > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
}

plugins { id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.4.RELEASE" }

ext { springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE' }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

jar {
    baseName = 'co-shoppu-common'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java:8.0'
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:4.3.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson'
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.0'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.9.Final'

    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.20'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}") }
}
```

complete stack is follows

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':common:compileJava'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:158)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:90)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:207)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:192)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:124)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at lombok.javac.handlers.HandleGetter.<clinit>(HandleGetter.java:303)
        at lombok.core.SpiLoadUtil$1$1.next(SpiLoadUtil.java:111)
        at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.loadAnnotationHandlers(HandlerLibrary.java:171)
        at lombok.javac.HandlerLibrary.load(HandlerLibrary.java:156)
        at lombok.javac.JavacTransformer.<init>(JavacTransformer.java:44)
        at lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor.init(LombokProcessor.java:89)
        at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor$JavacDescriptor.want(AnnotationProcessor.java:87)
        at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor.init(AnnotationProcessor.java:140)
        at lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor.init(AnnotationProcessor.java:69)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:674)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:771)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:866)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$2100(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:110)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1202)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1311)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1250)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:928)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:142)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags
        at lombok.launch.ShadowClassLoader.loadClass(ShadowClassLoader.java:422)
        at lombok.javac.JavacTreeMaker$SchroedingerType.getFieldCached(JavacTreeMaker.java:156)
        at lombok.javac.JavacTreeMaker$TypeTag.typeTag(JavacTreeMaker.java:245)
        at lombok.javac.Javac.<clinit>(Javac.java:155)
        ... 74 more
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the error (run gradle with `-s`)

Comment: @larsgrefer updated the stack error

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @larsgrefer i was using java 10, now tried with java 8 and worked perfectly thanks for your help and you can post the answer i'll up vote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Lombok version you are using is not compatible with your javac version.

The highest supported javac version of Lombok 1.16.20 is 9

Comment: If you are building on Java 10/11 you should upgrade to Lombok 1.18.4 or later.  (According to the Lombok changelog.)

Answer (score 4):

It was due to the java version i was trying in Java 10 and i switched to java 8 and it works,

Answer (score 4):

The highest supported javac version of Lombok 1.16.20 is 9 just as larsgrefer stated earlier but there is an edge version that supports and runs with Java 10.
Here is a link to the edge version.

https://projectlombok.org/download-edge

I use it in my project and it runs successfully.